# Byobu doesn't source /etc/profile.d scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, byobu

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and byobu.  One of the scripts I have in /etc/profile.d will enable bash completion for kubectl and helm for all users.  It works when the user logs in but not once they run byobu.

I have the feeling that maybe byobu isn't running bash as a login shell?  If so how could I make that change for all users or is there a better way to get byobu to source /etc/profile.d?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash completion not working in subshell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449592/bash-completion-not-working-in-subshell)

Comment: What are the contents of the user's `~/.bashrc`? If I delete mine, `complete` returns nothing. The `bash_completion` stuff at the end of the default `.bashrc` (`/etc/skel/.bashrc`) are responsible for fixing this for non-login shells, as bash completion cannot be inherited by subshells.

Comment: My user's .bashrc has the completion code commented out at the bottom.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449592/bash-completion-not-working-in-subshell does explain why it isn't working very well.

Comment: Also the same commented out code to enable completion is in /etc/bash.bashrc.  It feels a little weird top enable it there as users may want a non-interactive shell. Is there a way to make the system default byobu behavior to use a 'bash --login'?

Comment: The corresponding code block at `/etc/bash.bashrc` is commented out for me and by default. It seems this is loaded before the user's .bashrc, and will force enable it for all users. However, in this case, that's exactly what you wanted in the question. If this solution you found is tested to work, please post an answer!

Comment: Completion setup code shouldn't be in `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile`. That should go in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`. Otherwise they'd lose those settings just by stating a new shell by running `bash`

Comment: @muru it seems that is how Bash completion on Ubuntu 20.04 is set up, under /etc/profile.d.

Comment: When looking at the default tmux profile in /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmux, it has a comment that it uses $SHELL in order to not source /etc/profile.  What are the downsides of sourcing /etc/profile that it would be avoiding?

Comment: @rje no, it's actually done `~/.bashrc`. Check the last few lines of the default bashrc here: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/tree/debian/skel.bashrc?h=applied/ubuntu/focal#n108 The bash-completion package _additionally_ adds that config to `/etc/profile.d/bash-completion` as well, but most users would only be getting affected by the lines in `~/.bashrc` (since the default terminal programs all run non-login shells by default).

Comment: @muru You're right!  I was using 'sudo su -' to do some administrative tasks and the default .bashrc in root's home has a different bash_completion variant and that is commented out.

Comment: Ah, that one's from [the `base-files` package](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/tree/share/dot.bashrc?h=applied/ubuntu/focal-updates#n94), which sets up [root's profile and bashrc](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/tree/debian/postinst.in?h=applied/ubuntu/focal-updates). That package provides the initial `passwd`, `shadow`, `group`, etc. files with the root user already defined, which is why it has to set up root's dotfiles itself and can't use the skeleton files. Probably they just forgot to sync the two bashrc files.